# I need to split a cell value into different cells based on delimiter values using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel, which as a long line in a single cell(For example in "A1" in Sheet1) and I need to split this single cell and paste into different consecutive cell in Sheet1 itself in a cells A1,A2,A3 ., so on. But the challenge is that I have the delimiter values in another sheet(Sheet2).

Single cell("A1") line in Sheet1 is,

2012-06-02-13.01.29.64179044558000358307267 CAB2019012018 12345612345678Scenario 1     0000000000000000000000000000000000DoeNN

And the delimiters are in Sheet2(delimiters values are in different consecutive cells),

4(A1),5(A2),6(A3),2(A4),3(A5),5(A6),6(A7),1(A8),5(A9),7(A10),5(A11),9(A12)

I tried with below code,

```
Sub split_work()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cell_value As Variant
Dim counter As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws1
    str = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
    MStr = ws2.Cells(Lengthrow, j).Value
    'MStr = Left(str, MStr)

''These lines is to extract only the value from the cells in Sheet2 as a delimiter value, for example val=4, then we are extracting only 4 as delimiters,
    MStr = Cells(Lengthrow, j).Value
    MStr1 = InStrRev(MStr, "=")
    Length = Len(MStr)
    Mstr = Right(MStr, Length - MStr1)


For Each Item In WrdArray
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, 2).Value = Item
    counter = counter + 1
Next Item

End with

End sub
```

Please help me with this!

Comment: can you add the result after too? It's not quite clear

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  In particular, (in English) a delimiter is a sequence of one or more characters that separates two regions.  Your list of delimiters cannot possibly apply to your data.  Perhaps you are using an incorrect term?  But even if the values represent the length of each segment, the results seem illogical.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this might work for you.

```
Sub split_work()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim pStr As String
Dim delimiter As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim lStr As Integer

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

pStr = ws1.Range("A1")
delimiter = ws2.Range("A1")
counter = 0

Do While delimiter <> ""
dpos = InStr(pStr, delimiter)
ws1.Range("A1").Offset(counter, 1) = Left(pStr, dpos)
lStr = Len(pStr)
pStr = Right(pStr, lStr - dpos)
counter = counter + 1
delimiter = ws2.Range("A1").Offset(counter, 0)
Loop

If pStr <> "" Then
ws1.Range("A1").Offset(counter, 1) = pStr
End If

End Sub
```

I'm not sure if you are using those values as delimiters or positions for splitting in your string. I've assumed you are wanting to split the string when the code finds that substring.

Also, do you want to include or exclude that value from the string? In the above code I have included that value, please provide more information in your question so I can better answer your question.